# ORA-00845 after deleting files accidentally at /dev/shm

Tags: oracle, memory

I have two instances (ORA1 and ORA2) of Oracle 11g at the same machine. One is starting the other cannot startup anymore.

What happend:

First my disk was full, so I accidentally deleted all ora*-files under /dev/shm. After deleting other files I had enough disk space to start instance ORA2. But when I tried to start ORA1, I get ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system

I cannot even start ORA1 in nomount phase:
    SQL> startup nomount;
    ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system

ORA1 and ORA2 should be configurated equally. /dev/shm has 2G and following parameter are set in ORA2:

```
SQL> show parameter target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
archive_lag_target                   integer     0
db_flashback_retention_target        integer     1440
fast_start_io_target                 integer     0
fast_start_mttr_target               integer     0
memory_max_target                    big integer 0
memory_target                        big integer 0
parallel_servers_target              integer     32
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 382M
sga_target                           big integer 1152M
```

What needs to be done? Any hints or explanation appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The /dev/shm mount point should have twice as much space to allow both instances to run concurrently.

Comment: Hope you have a backup?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli Which value do you mean? sga_target?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Nop I probably haven't a backup, since it is just a testing environment - are these files really necessary to startup Oracle? As much as I know about these files they are just temporary Working Memory files, aren't they?

Answer (score 3):

As described in https://www.krenger.ch/blog/ora-00845-memory_target-not-supported-on-this-system/ and suggestion of MarcoBaldelli /dev/shm just needs to have enough space. So the solution was to increase /dev/shm:

```
mount -o remount,size=4G /dev/shm
```

When MEMORY_TARGET is set to 0 (as in my case) it seems to be as following (see [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory003.htm#ADMIN11199)):

For the MEMORY_MAX_TARGET initialization parameter, decide on a maximum amount of memory that you would want to allocate to the database for the foreseeable future. That is, **determine the maximum value for the sum of the SGA and instance PGA sizes**. This number can be larger than or the same as the MEMORY_TARGET value that you chose in the previous step.